How to obtain authorization to access EKS cluster
Followed this document Cert Signing to get the certificate issued.
I created cluster role and role binding to test it.
$ kubectl auth can-i create pods --as=myserver
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i list pods --as=myserver
no
$ kubectl auth can-i delete secrets  --as=myserver
no

and
$ kubectl auth can-i create pods --user=myserver


error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

How to get "certificate-authority", its EKS cluster?
Is there a command to setup the kubectl config to utilize the .key and .crt file in order to access the cluster?
Issues status

The AWS CLI provides a command to setup the kubeconfig for connecting to E
aws eks update-kubeconfig ...


To acquire approval to get to an Amazon EKS bunch, you normally arrange Kubernetes RBAC (Job-Based Admittance Control) utilizing AWS IAM jobs. This involves configuring kubeconfig files or the AWS CLI to securely authenticate and access the cluster, assigning roles to users or AWS services, and creating IAM policies that grant permissions for cluster operations.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
